# Overheated laptop

Tags: windows

My laptop got heated up and then there was some spark n smoke n it got shutdown. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 7):

If there was 'smoke and fire' you very probably have device failures and need servicing.

Reasons that could lead to this,

1. Did you have the laptop vents blocked?
   Like, were you working on the bed or a mattress?
2. Do you work in a hot and/or humid environment?
3. Does your adapter still work (if it has a LED light on it, does it still glow)?
4. Do you suspect quality of the power delivered from the source you were using when this happened?

Comment: If there was 'smoke and fire' you very probably need a new laptop!

Comment: @Josh: Was about to say the same...he most likely fried it.

Comment: @Josh, @Bobby, Gee guys, do you have to terrify people who already have a stalled laptop?

Comment: If my laptop was emitting sparks and smoke I think terror would be justified. I don't think that's a good feature...

Comment: @Josh, right. But, if someone has such trouble, it is not very justified to jump to the worst-case statements on a forum without even a picture to judge things. Yet, I am fine if you want to make these statements :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that it was a failure of the active cooling system, anything from the fan to the fan controller or even just the heatsink becoming disconnected through mis-treatment of the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I know certain tech geeks who insist on taking off the lower covering of their laptop whenever they go hardcore gaming or into any other process that requires a lot of CPU usage. This helps a LOT in fact but for most normal people this isn’t the obvious *way to go* solution. So what can you do to prevent your laptop from overheating then?

- **Don’t use in high temperatures**

Don’t use your laptop when the temperature is high (Above 40 degrees). This might cause your laptop to overheat very quickly (as normally the laptop is hotter than the outside temperature, which is called the base temperature).

- **Prevent use in humid conditions**

Don’t use your laptop for a very long time (exceeding two hours) or for gaming when the conditions are above 60% humid. Because this causes the hot air blown out of the laptop to find it difficult to escape (Since vapor is generally denser than normal air and the molecules find it pave their way out)

- **NEVER Block the vents**

Your Laptop’s air outlets or vents are its best friends, NEVER block them, especially the vents at the bottom of the laptop, they put a lot of air out, therefore always keep your laptop on something which provides sufficient area for the hot air to escape (preferably some sort of a stand). If you keep your laptop on your lap, try to put something on your lap first so it doesn’t block the vents.

- **Never leave a running laptop closed**

Sometimes people tend to leave their running laptops closed, as in, they powered a laptop on but didn’t turn it off and just closed it that way and kept it inside some enclosed place. If you do this, there is a high chance your laptop’s hardware gets fried due to the trapping of hot air.

- **Don’t go hardcore**

Laptops are meant for casual usage, yet sometimes people insist on gaming on their laptops, there is no problem with gaming on a laptop, but when you go on for a LONG time (2 hours plus) it becomes inevitable for the laptop to sustain some damage due to overheating caused by your actions. Not just gaming, this applies even to the usage of softwares which are high on CPU usage (Photoshop, CS, Flashy GUI stuff). If you want to game/use these softwares, do it, but try not to exceed a few hours.

- **Turn your laptop OFF sometimes**

A lot of people don’t turn their laptop off, which is not just a major cause of all overheating problems, but actually of ALL laptop problems. Ideally, one should turn their laptop off for at least five-six hours everyday so that it is cooled off. By cooled off I don’t mean the cooling of the outer crust, but there are SEVERAL internal parts of laptops which don’t cool easily, they need time, and to get the most out of your laptop, you need to take care of them as well.

- **Get more cooling**

You could install some extra cooling for your laptop, something like a small water cooler, you know the ones found in certain high end gaming CPU’s, something like that, and then you could affix a place for the actual blower inside the laptop in a way such that the cooler could be taken out and carried with you and your laptop, it would require extra power supply of course.

- **Clean your Laptop sometimes**

You must clean the internal area of your laptop sometimes, the recommended time is every two months. IF you believe you cannot do it, take your laptop to some repair shop and get it done. A laptop is frequently exposed to outside surroundings and hence has the biggest chance of catching dust hence obstructing the flow of hot air to the outside of the laptop.
Also, if ever your Laptop gets overheated and shuts down (for the first time) DO NOT turn it on until it has cooled off, or else there is a big possibility your laptop would get overheated and get some permanent damage on it.

[Source](http://www.technewspulse.com/tips-for-overheated-laptops/)

Comment: you mean 40 degrees C, or F?

Comment: Are you joking or...

Comment: He probably means 40°C (and should update his answer about it). Also, how is 40°C a "high" temperature, for a laptop? I almost start mine at this temp. You should worry when it passes 75°-85°. Of course it depends on the laptop, but I think 40°C is a bit low to start worrying about.

Comment: Also, there are laptops made for gaming/intensive use, so the "don't go hardcore" seems a bit silly then. It might have been true a few years ago, but laptops are becoming more powerful, especially with the increased demand.

Comment: And what are these vents on the bottom of the laptop?  None of the ones I bought or used had them.  The appeared to be designed to sit on a desk or table.

Comment: @warren:  If it's 40 below, it doesn't matter whether it's C or F.

Comment: @David Thornley: true enough - though I'd love for my desktops to run at 40K, personally =)

Comment: @warren:  I'd like to be able to get near my desktop without frostbite, though, and I'd worry that the frozen nitrogen and oxygen would mess something up.

Comment: does N2 solidify by 40K? I know it hits liquid at 77.. but with decent-enough insulation, it's not bad